# Transform a list, without having patterns to replace

Tags: python, list, transform

I have a list like this one:

```
['10.131.0.240/29-NameoftheNetwork-8-8-0', '10.121.0.248/29-NameoftheNetwork2-8-8-0', '10.111.2.248/29-NameoftheNetwork3-8-7-1']
```

The three final numbers of each value are: Total IPs / Used IPs / Left IPs.

**I only want to take the "Left IPs" for each network, transforming this:**

```
['10.131.0.240/29-NameoftheNetwork-8-8-0', '10.121.0.248/29-NameoftheNetwork2-8-8-0', '10.111.2.248/29-NameoftheNetwork3-8-7-1']
```

**To something like this:**

```
['10.131.0.240/29-NameoftheNetwork=0', '10.121.0.248/29-NameoftheNetwork2=0', '10.111.2.248/29-NameoftheNetwork3=1']
```

But I do not find a way to remove the characters that I dont want, and I do not have a pattern that repeats to replace it for nothing or "=".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re

data = ['10.131.0.240/29-NameoftheNetwork-8-8-0', '10.121.0.248/29-NameoftheNetwork2-8-8-0', '10.111.2.248/29-NameoftheNetwork3-8-7-1']
data = [re.sub(r"(.*?)\-\d+\-\d+\-(\d+)", r"\1=\2", i) for i in data]
print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
['10.131.0.240/29-NameoftheNetwork=0', '10.121.0.248/29-NameoftheNetwork2=0', '10.111.2.248/29-NameoftheNetwork3=1']
```